# Jquery the result of combined select and some variable's value works just for the first select change

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, sum, onchange

Hi all i spent whole the night to do a bit complex (for me) script and unfortunately i didn't get the solution

i do some select and store it in a input box with name "TOT"

every select on change sum a value to this field

after that i have to sum Field "carriera" + the value stored into  "TOT"
after divide it to 11

**the script works just for the first change**  not if i do more changes in other select.

this is my Jsfiddle  , i hope someone could help me
http://jsfiddle.net/swedenfox/dfqb38ts/5/

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
            // Variables
            var somma = 0;
            var a = 0;
            var b = 0;
            var d = 11;
                var inputone = $('#noneditabile').val();
                var multiplierone = $('#carriera').val();
            //SELECT ON CHanGE
            $('select').change(function () {
                var sum = 0;

                $('select :selected').each(function () {
                    sum += parseInt($(this).val());
                });
                parseInt($("span.uneditable-input").html(sum));
                var a = $("span.uneditable-input").val();
                up();
            });
            //SELECT ON CHanGE

            $(function () {
                var number = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 40) + 60;
                $("#carriera").val(number);
            });
            //some function to add select and the random value
            function up() {
                var d = 11;
                var inputone = $('#noneditabile').val();
                var multiplierone = $('#carriera').val();

                //var inputtwo = $('#inputtwo').val();
                //var multipliertwo = $('#multipliertwo').val();
                var totalTotalOne = (inputone + multiplierone);
                var totalTotalTwo = parseFloat((totalTotalOne / d).toFixed(2));
                // $('#totale').text(totalTotalOne);
                $('#totale').text(totalTotalTwo);
            }
                ;
            function updatePrice(val)
            {
                $("span.uneditable-input").val(val);
                $("span.uneditable-input").trigger('change');
            }



        });
```

**EDIT**
Sorry i'll try to explain it better 
I'd like to get the total for each options selected by the user (all the dropdown box), at the moment the script calculates only the first change.

this script would like to make a sum of two input fields disabled
*this is a random number*
              Carriera dello Studente

*and this is the sum of value="" in all the selected box*
                    TOT

After that those fields are populated i would like to sum both and divide the result /11

**EDIT 2**

SOLVED 
THIS IS THE SOLUTION i needed thanks to the contributors to help me reach the error

http://jsfiddle.net/swedenfox/dfqb38ts/8/

Comment: *"every select on change sum a value to this field

after that i have to sum Field "carriera" + the value stored into "TOT" after divide it to 11"* - What do you mean by *"after that"*? after what? *"divide it to 11"* - did you mean devide *by* 11? what is *it*?

Comment: the sum of the values in all selected options in <option value="0"> go to a field   ---> $("span.uneditable-input").val()   after that i sum this value stored there with $('#carriera').val() and after i divided [$('#carriera').val() + $("span.uneditable-input").val() ] / 11   [link]http://jsfiddle.net/swedenfox/dfqb38ts/5/

Comment: Please don't post code snippets in comments... [edit] your question and update it with the relevant information...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `var inputone = $('#noneditabile').val();` to `var inputone = $('#noneditabile').text();`

> 'noneditabile' is a span element with text and has no value.

See update of your code here:
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dfqb38ts/6/)

Comment: thanks a lot Gregory :)

Comment: Gregory i updated the fiddle , this is the solution i needed http://jsfiddle.net/swedenfox/dfqb38ts/8/   thx a lot for helping me to find the error